# chart axis label format vba settings

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing vb script to generate charts. On the X axis, I have have the date and on the Y axis, the temp.

On the X axis I want to present time with the format "dd-mm". My data looks like this:

```
2014-06-17 01:00
2014-06-17 02:00
2014-06-17 03:00
2014-06-17 04:00
2014-06-17 05:00
2014-06-17 06:00
2014-06-17 07:00
2014-06-17 08:00
2014-06-17 09:00
```

And this is what I have written in vb script so far:

```
 With chtChart.Chart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = sheetName & vbCr & "2014"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd-mm"

    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Temperature [C]"
    End With
```

Unfortunately, when I generate the chart, the entire date value (e.g. 2014-06-07 01:00) is being applied to the X axis.

Any thoughts/ideas on how I can fix what I have?

Update:

whole code to create charts:

```
Function AddChartSheet(sheetName As String, title As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim chtChart As ChartObject
   Dim measDataSheetName As String
   'Create a new chart.
   measDataSheetName = sheetName & "_measurements.csv"

   Dim Lastrow As Integer
   Dim seriesNames() As String

   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.name = sheetName & " chart"
   Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName & " chart")

   Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=25, Top:=25, _
        Width:=700, Height:=500)

    With chtChart
        .name = sheetName
    End With


   Lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(measDataSheetName).Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(measDataSheetName).Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Ro

  With chtChart.Chart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = sheetName & vbCr & "2014"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd-mm"

    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Temperature [C]"
    End With

   With chtChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .name = "Supply"
      .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

      .XValues = Worksheets(measDataSheetName).Range("P2:P" & Lastrow) '. SelectRange("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown))
      .Values = Worksheets(measDataSheetName).Range("T2:T" & Lastrow)

   End With


   With chtChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .name = "Return"
      .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

      .XValues = Worksheets(measDataSheetName).Range("P2:P" & Lastrow) '. SelectRange("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown))
      .Values = Worksheets(measDataSheetName).Range("U2:U" & Lastrow)

   End With
   AddChartSheet = True

End Function
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you sure `chtChart.Chart` is the object you look at? Furthermore, are you sure dates are read as such and not rather as strings? You can debug it like this: 1) the first point, try to write `chtChart.Chart.Activate` and see if it pops-up. 2) the second point, try to write `A1-1` (say a date is in range `A1` and observe if you get a value error).

Comment: isDate method returns true on those values....

Comment: What do you get when you check the number formatting after this code runs?  Does it show "dd-mm" or some other value?  Also what happens if you **set the formatting logic after you create the new series**?  Excel might be overwriting your formatting once it detects the data type of the new series.  This might be more likely since you're also changing the chart type with those new series.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i did find solution: add formatting after sending data:

```
 With chtChart.Chart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = sheetName & vbCr & "2014"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd-mm"

    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Temperature [C]"
    End With

   With chtChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .name = "Supply"
      .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

      .XValues = Worksheets(measDataSheetName).Range("P2:P" & Lastrow) '. SelectRange("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown))
      .Values = Worksheets(measDataSheetName).Range("T2:T" & Lastrow)

   End With

 With chtChart.Chart
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd-mm"

   End With
```

and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to swap x and y axis is:

```
Activechart.plotby = xcolumns
```